# c++ : std::map operations on different maps in different threads appears to cause a SIGILL crash?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

On an embedded ARM system, I had an odd crash today where a map `.clear()` operation caused an illegal instruction, and curiously a different thread was accessing a *different* map but that thread stack was using similar stl map functions at the time (`std::_RB_tree`). I was curious what might cause such a thing. The map in thread B is intended to be read-only, though I realize `map::operator[]` counts as a write, I since changed it to `.at()`.

I don't believe I've seen a crash at this point in the code before. No other thread was in a point where it would be accessing either map.

Stack A:

```
   Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread 1117324432 (LWP 1414)]
0x00433e04 in std::_Rb_tree<SensorEnumType, std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string> >, std::less<SensorEnumType>, std::allocator<std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string> > >::_M_leftmost (this=0xff0a0000)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:449
449     /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h: No such file or directory.
        in /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00433e04 in std::_Rb_tree<SensorEnumType, std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string> >, std::less<SensorEnumType>, std::allocator<std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string> > >::_M_leftmost (this=0xff0a0000)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:449
#1  0x00434e0c in std::map<SensorEnumType, std::string, std::less<SensorEnumType>, std::allocator<std::pair<SensorEnumType const, std::string> > >::clear (
    this=0x5bd840)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:501
#2  0x00430f8c in SensorMap::SensorMapClear (this=0x5bd824,
    maptable=@0x4298f884) at ---
...
```

Stack B:

```
[Switching to thread 4 (Thread 1116062864 (LWP 1391))]#0  0x40ca22cc in memcmp
    () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x40ca22cc in memcmp () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x40b47dd8 in std::string::compare () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x001e7308 in std::operator< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (__lhs=@0x64e318, __rhs=@0x4285bb50)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:2213
#3  0x0039bc70 in std::less<std::string>::operator() (this=0x5c4f40,
    __x=@0x64e318, __y=@0x4285bb50)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:227
#4  0x0041bd7c in std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, datalogDefTableRow>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, datalogDefTableRow> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, datalogDefTableRow> > >::lower_bound (this=0x5c4f40, __k=@0x4285bb50)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1371
#5  0x0041be6c in std::map<std::string, datalogDefTableRow, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, datalogDefTableRow> > >::lower_bound (this=0x5c4f40, __x=@0x4285bb50)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueab---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
i/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:576
#6  0x0041e738 in std::map<std::string, datalogDefTableRow, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, datalogDefTableRow> > >::operator[] (this=0x5c4f40, __k=@0x4285bb50)
    at /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_map.h:345
#7  0x003f18cc in getDatalogTableRow (item=@0x4285bb50, row=@0x4285baf0)
    at ---
...
```

Any insight is appreciated.